# How to connect Ubuntu to University LAN (Windows, Dynamic IPs) to use Internet

Tags: networking, internet

I have recently switched from Windows to Ubuntu so I don't know much about it. The issue is that I am unable to connect my Ubuntu laptop with the computer laboratory of my university via LAN cable so that I can use internet.

When I had Windows installed in my laptop, I would go to the Lab and plugin the networking cable into my laptop's socket. Then I would Disable the Local Area Connection and then Enable it. I had to disable it because in my university the Computer Science department provides internet to all other departments and it has multiple network names, for example Network 24, Network 26, etc.

So every time I disabled and re-enabled the Local Area Connection, it would connect my Windows laptop to a random network and the Internet turned on.

Secondly, the PCs in Lab have specific IP addresses like 192.168.1.253. But I didn't need to put any IP Address or sub-net mask or anything in my Local Area Connection's properties. I would just have the settings on "Automatically Obtain IP Addresses" and then I Disabled and then Enabled the Local Area Connection.

Now I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 in my laptop and I am unable to connect my laptop with university network for using Internet. I put my Ubuntu Wired Connection IPV4 settings to "Automatic DHCP", but it didn't connect me to internet.

Now plz don't tell me to ask the Lab administrator because he only knows how to open Youtube :) Also don't tell me to switch back to Windows because I loathe viruses.

Please help me solving this. I need it because the University has acquired some online subscriptions so that students can access journals for the research work. I'll be grateful for the help.

P.S: Following are the results of the codes...

```
ahmad@ahmad-laptop:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
03:01.0 CardBus bridge: O2 Micro, Inc. OZ601/6912/711E0 CardBus/SmartCardBus Controller (rev 40)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5752 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 02)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01)
```

and

```
ahmad@ahmad-laptop:~$ sudo lshw -c network
[sudo] password for ahmad: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dfdfc000-dfdfffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5752 Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:14:22:fa:dc:ba
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.123 firmware=5752-v3.19 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:44 memory:dfcf0000-dfcfffff
```

The result of ifconfig is following..

ahmad@ahmad-laptop:~$ ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:14:22:fa:dc:ba  
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::214:22ff:fefa:dcba/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:16261 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:378 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1275717 (1.2 MB)  TX bytes:41326 (41.3 KB)
          Interrupt:18 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:292 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:21054 (21.0 KB)  TX bytes:21054 (21.0 KB)
```

Comment: is your card detected in ubuntu? what message is shown when you plugged the cable? please edit your question and include result of `lspci`, `sudo lshw -c network` & `ifconfig` ( `ifconfig` after you plugged the cable, other two you can post now). If the message is showing connected and page is not opening, try `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yest my card is detected and when I plug the LAN cable it says connection established but web pages don't open. I have included the results of first two codes.

Comment: Thaks for edit. give us `ifconfig` & `ping 8.8.8.8` result. Most possibly you are using some proxy. You can get the proxy config from IE (a [referance](http://www.wikihow.com/Enter-Proxy-Settings-in-Internet-Explorer)) & apply same to ubuntu. If you can ping 8.8.8.8, then you are connected to internet but dns is not working. Put 8.8.8.8 as dns server in connectin properties.

Comment: BTW, your wireless card is not enabled.[Refer this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx) to get it working.

Comment: Yes my wireless is not working, I tried to install fwcutter using some tutorial, but in vain.

Comment: I couldn't get the result of ifconfig today, but I think I have found a workaround. If I go to edit connections and delete the wired connection and then re-create the wired connection, internet starts working. But I don't want to do this every time.

Comment: The result of ifconfig is added to the question above, and when I type ( ifconfig, it just gives "<" this thing.

Comment: It is probably late, but what you described is DHCP. Once the network configured *(the «automatic dhcp» connection you created; ah, and set, at least while it didn't work, the «Connect automatically» option)*, to diagnose the problem you would need to remove cable, execute `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, press enter to separate the new text that would appear, plug the cable in, wait a bit while the wall of text stopped, and copy everything that appeared after you plugged in the cable into this post. My guess is that the LAN is owned by some weird security policies, and we need to find, which ones.